# Subscribe to an example

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, notifications

In the same way that you can can subscribe to issues on Github, it would be cool to subscribe to an example to get notified if it gets modified, moved or deleted.

Comment: The reason you'd subscribe to an issue on github is so you can get notified when progess is made towards its fix.. why would you subscribe to an example?

Comment: @Sayse Because you are an expert on the subject and you wanna monitor the changes?

Answer (score 1):

As of a couple days ago, watching an example will get you notifications if an improvement is requested or a change is proposed.

Comment: You mean you have to click on *view discussion* and then *watch*? Couldn't we watch the example directly?