# How do I unfollow a post?

Tags: feature-request

I occasionally participate in a question that subsequently receives responses or other activity that no longer interest me. How do I deactivate my connection to any given post so that I no longer get inbox notifications from it? To be clear, I don't want to turn off inbox notifications entirely - I'm interested in stopping notifications on an individual, per-post basis.

Comment: Don't think you can.  But if I understand you correctly, you don't want to get inbox notifications for a question?  Did you author it?

Comment: @Makoto - I don't currently have any posts that I've authored and want to unfollow, no. I'd like to be able to unfollow any post, but the ability to unfollow posts that I didn't author would be a step forward. If this isn't possible, I'll change this question's tag.

Comment: @Makoto is correct - you can't do this at the moment.

Comment: How can you follow a post that is not your own? Did you write a comment?

Comment: @dur - You can get notifications on a question/answer/page with a comment or by being the deciding vote on a closure. I realize now that I was using "post" ambiguously above; my apologies.

Comment: Then an answer could be, remove all your comments. I suppose, that you don't want this, right?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, and I think our model just never imagined the signal-to-noise ratio would become so low as to prompt a 3 years old, 31k user to find a way to dismiss (not be bothered anymore by) further discussion on questions they contributed to.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - I rarely want to do this, but it would be a very nice thing to have sometimes.

Comment: @Tiger, rarely how much? Please quantify this (e.g. as intents per week, floats welcome).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - I haven't been keeping track, but my rough estimate is somewhere between 0.2 to 0.5.

Comment: @Tiger, well, I'm afraid two intents per month will probably not fly -- if you're alone. Other users still might support this feature request. Let's see what comes out of this.

Comment: Coincidentally, I was just looking that option last week. Thought maybe I overlooked it. It is not an every day occurrence for me either, but a few times the option to "mute" a thread  would come in handy.

Comment: [In other news](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330049/248058), we want a way to do it on the documentation side.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I think you can only be pinged due to a close vote if you used a dupehammer. Or if you are a mod.

Comment: I'd really like this to be looked at. I'm getting tired of closing questions and getting spammed with notifications whining that the duplicate isn't a true Scotsman.