# Finding missing documentation

Tags: support, documentation

I was just answering a question on SO about a JDBC related question,

Perfect! I wrote up a nice long example with comments and details on Docs.. now just to find it..

I have gone through all of my personal history, and contributions on my profile -

This post that I *know* I wrote, can not be found - even searching through Documentation, I can not find it.

I remember my post had been written in `Java`, I believe the Topic was `JDBC`, which no longer seems to exist for the language.

It now appears as if there is a whole Category for `jdbc`, however my post is not their either.

Was my article deleted? Was it moved or renamed?
Should I have gotten a notification?

And why does it no longer appear in my personal history.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The topic was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/77286?filter-tags=java).

Because the topic doesn't exist, the only thing still showing on your profile is the change you made:

[image: User profile]

Going to the topic (title is linked in the change above), gives an option to view the last revision prior to deletion:

[image: Deleted topic]

If you want to move some of the content to the [jdbc docs](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jdbc/topics), as that's related to the deletion reason.

---

So, the content is still in your profile - just it's rather convoluted to get to...  I'll ping the team about options to surface this a little more clearly (probably on contributions).

As to notifications: right now, no you shouldn't get a notification when something is deleted.  The Discussion feature under development will introduce some new notification options, though we're still debating whether a change will opt you in to future notifications on the modified topic.

---

**Update**

As of the latest build, there's another way to get at any deleted topic or example you've made significant contributions to.

[image: Show deleted]

This list does not include trivial (less than 20 non-formatting, non-whitespace, characters changed) changes.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330049/248058

Comment: @knu [(ugly) screenshot from my local build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DA71E.png)

Comment: Where's my [meta-tag:status-planned]?

Comment: Silently nuking people's carefully-crafted and useful content. Awesome! I'm sure Matt is just _thrilled_ about how his work has been treated here...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I don't see the problem of silently nuking content. It's already this way with Q&A. You may put a lot of effort to write an answer and you won't be notified if it is deleted. The only exception is if there is a rep change, which the same applies for documentation, I guess.

Comment: @Zanon: _"It's already this way with Q&A"_ Not really; it's a lot harder to delete good, on-topic content in Q&A, so if your content has actually been removed then it was probably remove-worthy. That's not the case here.

Comment: As far as I recall, when I approved that deletion, I either moved the content, or checked if equivalent content already existed under JDBC. But then again, I started not caring about documentation a few days later, so I don't know what happened afterwards.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit here's a counter example IMO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39150814/248058. Was it "remove-worthy"? I think this is one of my favourite answers and probably one that would be quite useful for the community, but still it has been deleted.

Comment: @Knu: It's completely off-topic. This is not the proper format for "list" questions. Daniel's answer there was deleted because, being an answer to a blatantly off-topic question, it shouldn't have existed in the first place! I admit there are some current exceptions for severely needed canonical resources, such as the C++ book guide.